# Minimum specs for XAMPP server on Vista

Tags: windows, xampp

What do you recommend as minimum specs for a Windows laptop running Vista, an IDE, and Apache, MySQL, and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 GB ram
Pentium Core 2 Duo

Thats it

Comment: Though, I have an AMD budget laptop, which runs Vista fine.

But I would go with Core 2 Duo because I think it is a more wothwhile investment.

Comment: But, for a budget laptop (I am trying to stay in the 500 dollar range) you get a Intel graphics accelerator which isn't too nice.  A AMD processor gets you the ATI graphics accelerator.

Comment: Then get a AMD, It does not really matter, these days, budget laptops run Vista fine, as wel as XAMP.

Answer (score 1):

If a laptop is running Vista well (2GB and a decent video card) it will have no trouble with XAMP. For development, Apache, MySQL and PHP will use very little CPU or memory. They are all very efficient.